# Changing color with KeyListener

Tags: java, swing, methods, colors, keylistener

I have a project that a circle goes with random x and y values and with selected colors but when the user pressed the space bar the color of the circle must be changed. My circle moves both x and y coordinate and I want to change the color of the circle when I press the space button. But it does not work when I pressed it. It goes with its original color. So how can I make this code right?

```
public class c {
    private int x,y,r;
    private Color co;
    private int Re,G,B;
    private Random ran;

    public c() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        ran= new Random();
        x=100;
        y=50;
        r= ran.nextInt(200)+50;
        Re=ran.nextInt(255);
        G=ran.nextInt(255);
        B=ran.nextInt(255);
        co= new Color(Re,G,B); 
    }

    public int getRe() {
        return Re;
    }

    public int getG() {
        return G;
    }

    public int getB() {
        return B;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public int getR() {
        return r;
    }
    public void setCo(int Re,int G,int B) {
        co= new Color(Re,G,B);
    }
    public Color getCo() {
        return co;
    }

    public Random getRan() {
        return ran;
    }
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x=x;
    }
    public void setY(int y) {
    this.y=y;
    }

}



public class Circle extends JFrame implements ActionListener,KeyListener{

    private Timer timer;
    private int x,y,a=5,b=5;
    private Random rand;
    c circ = new c();
    public Circle() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        x=circ.getX();
        y=circ.getY();
        timer=new Timer(50,this);
        timer.start();
        addKeyListener(this);
        setSize(550,550);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.fillOval(x,y,100,100);
        g.setColor(circ.getCo());
    }


    public static void main(String[]args) {
        new Circle();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        moveWithTimer();
        repaint();      
    }

    public void moveWithTimer() {

        x=x+b;
        y=y+a;
    if(x<0) {
        b=5;
    }

    if(x+50>500) {
        b=-5;
    }

    if(y<0){
        a=5;
    }

    if(y+50>500) {
        a=-5;
    }



    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       if(e.getKeyCode()==e.VK_SPACE) {
           circ.setCo(rand.nextInt(255),rand.nextInt(255),rand.nextInt(255));


       }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But it does not work when I pressed it. It goes with its original color. So how can I make this code right?

`KeyListener` is fickle, better to use the [Key Bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which overcomes the primary, focus related, issues of `KeyListener`

As a general rule of thumb, you shouldn't override `paint` of top level containers like `JFrame`, they are compound components and it's just a real mess.

Instead, start with a `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method.  It's generally more flexible. Have a look at [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more details.

Your movement code is wrong.  You assign the `x`/`y` values of the circle class to some other variables, the problem here is, changing the values of these variables will have no affect on the variables in you circle class, instead, you need assign them back...

```
public void moveWithTimer() {
    int x = circ.getX();
    int y = circ.getY();

    x = x + b;
    y = y + a;
    if (x < 0) {
        b = 5;
    }

    if (x + 50 > 500) {
        b = -5;
    }

    if (y < 0) {
        a = 5;
    }

    if (y + 50 > 500) {
        a = -5;
    }

    circ.setX(x);
    circ.setY(y);

}
```

Your "circle" class could also use a couple of additional methods.  One to randomise the color (it already has a `Random` object, might as well use it) and one to paint the object.

```
public class Circle {
    //...

    public void paint(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d.setColor(co);
        g2d.fillOval(x, y, r * 2, r * 2);
    }

    //...

    public void randomColor() {
        setCo(ran.nextInt(255), ran.nextInt(255), ran.nextInt(255));
    }

    //...

}
```

If it was me, I'd be tempted to add a `move` method as well, but that's me ;)

As a runnable example...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Timer timer;
        private int a = 5, b = 5;
        private Random rand;
        private Circle circ = new Circle();

        public TestPane() {
            timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    moveWithTimer();
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();

            InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap am = getActionMap();
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0), "spaced");
            am.put("spaced", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    circ.randomColor();
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        public void moveWithTimer() {
            int x = circ.getX();
            int y = circ.getY();

            x = x + b;
            y = y + a;
            if (x < 0) {
                b = 5;
            }

            if (x + 50 > 500) {
                b = -5;
            }

            if (y < 0) {
                a = 5;
            }

            if (y + 50 > 500) {
                a = -5;
            }

            circ.setX(x);
            circ.setY(y);

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(500, 500);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            circ.paint(g2d);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

    public class Circle {

        private int x, y, r;
        private Color co;
        private int Re, G, B;
        private Random ran;

        public Circle() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            ran = new Random();
            x = 100;
            y = 50;
            r = ran.nextInt(50) + 50;
            Re = ran.nextInt(255);
            G = ran.nextInt(255);
            B = ran.nextInt(255);
            co = new Color(Re, G, B);
        }

        public void paint(Graphics2D g2d) {
            g2d.setColor(co);
            g2d.fillOval(x, y, r * 2, r * 2);
        }

        public int getRe() {
            return Re;
        }

        public int getG() {
            return G;
        }

        public int getB() {
            return B;
        }

        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }

        public int getR() {
            return r;
        }

        public void randomColor() {
            setCo(ran.nextInt(255), ran.nextInt(255), ran.nextInt(255));
        }

        public void setCo(int Re, int G, int B) {
            co = new Color(Re, G, B);
        }

        public Color getCo() {
            return co;
        }

        public Random getRan() {
            return ran;
        }

        public void setX(int x) {
            this.x = x;
        }

        public void setY(int y) {
            this.y = y;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you should set the color of the graphics object within paint(g) *before* painting the circle.

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.setColor(circ.getCo());
    g.fillOval(x,y,100,100);
}
```

In general, you should not override the paint() method of the JFrame. Instead, create a JPanel, add it to your frame and override the paintComponent() method of the panel.